# how to use accents like en-au in gTTS?

Tags: python, gtts

i'm trying to change the accent of gTTS from the default to another (en-uk, en-au, en-za, whichever). It works fine when i set it to

```
tts = gTTS(text=audio_string, lang='en',slow=False)
```

but not when I set it to anything else, like

```
tts = gTTS(text=audio_string, lang='en-au',slow=False)
```

or even

```
tts = gTTS(text=audio_string, lang='en-us',slow=False)
```

other languages work fine as long as I don't specify an accent. why is this? thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You can check [Localized ‘accents’ and Examples](https://gtts.readthedocs.io/en/latest/module.html#localized-accents) on gTTS documentation. It should be:

```
tts = gTTS(text=audio_string, tld='com.au', lang='en',  slow=False)
```